# Qual o método correspondente ao FindAll do List é usado em um DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Tenho o seguinte select abaixo:

```
var Filhos = FluxoWorkflow_
                .FindAll(N => N.IdPai.GetValueOrDefault() == dr.IdFluxoWorkflow);
```

Tive que altera a minha classe tipada para um `DataTable` só não estou conseguindo altera o select para buscar todos os dados correspondente no seguinte filtro:

```
.FindAll(N => N.IdPai.GetValueOrDefault() == dr.IdFluxoWorkflow);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`AsEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) para "converter" seu `DataTable` para um `IEnumerable<T>`, então você poder usar o [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) para filtrar os dados.

```
var Filhos = FluxoWorkflow_.AsEnumerable().
            .Where(N => N.IdPai.GetValueOrDefault() == dr.IdFluxoWorkflow);
```

---

**Obs.:** Os métodos [`FindAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) fazem a mesma coisa. A diferença entre eles é que o **`FindAll()` é um método de `List<T>`**, portanto só pode ser usado para esse tipo, enquanto o `Where()` é um método de extensão de `System.Linq` e é aplicável em qualquer tipo que implemente `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Não deu bem certo fazer dessa forma, estou usando o Framework v2.0 e muitas coisas não compila no IIS, mas consegui usando o select     `DataRow[] Filhos = FluxoWorkflow_
                .Select("[IdPai] =" + dr["IdFluxoWorkflow"]); `. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Tranquilo. Bom poder ajudar um pouco.